# Timer cancel after finished in Flutter

Tags: flutter, timer

```
Timer(_loadingDuration, () {
      _isOpenShowDialog = true;

      if (_controllerIsReversed) {
        _controllerIsReversed = false;
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }).cancel();
```

After finished timer working, can I cancel my timer like this?

Comment: Use future delayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cancel` is used to prevent the callback from being called before `Duration` expires. Calling `cancel` afterwards will have no effect.

That being said, calling cancel as you are in your code will cancel the `Timer` immediately, so your callback will never be called.